# What qualifies as CSI (comprehensive sickness insurance) in Switzerland?

Tags: insurance

The UK requires CSI (comprehensive sickness insurance) for some certain documents. Their definition of what is and what isn't CSI isn't totally clear though. Here's an idea of what they say it is:

> You must take a proportionate approach when you consider if an insurance policy is comprehensive. For example, a policy may contain certain exemptions but if the policy covers the applicant for medical treatment in the majority of circumstances you can accept it.

and what they say it isn't:

> The definition of CSI does not include:
>
> - cash back health schemes, such as:
>
>   - dental
>   - optical
>   - prescription charges
> - travel insurance policies
> - access to the UK’s NHS

What would qualify as CSI for people living in Switzerland? (Local or international)

Comment: Is this something required for Swiss citizens in order for them to settle or travel in the UK or is this something that the UK government requires UK citizens living or traveling in Switzerland to purchase? Also, what does it mean to require it "for some certain documents"? Did you mean "for some certain immigrants" or similar?

Comment: CSI for EU+ nationals wishing to reside in UK should be in Expat. In any case, EHIC (through your basic compulsory insurance) should be enough for temporary stays (e.g. students). Otherwise I don't think your original country of residence is relevant.

Comment: @zhantongz Does coverage need to begin in country of origin?

Comment: We still need more information. What do you mean by "some certain documents?" What uk.gov documents or UK government web pages contain this requirement? What do you mean by "...living in Switzerland (Local or international)?"